# Add arguments in enum cases. getting error : 'Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments'

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to do something like that:

```swift
public enum MyEnum: String {
  case tapOnSection(section: String) = "tap on \(section)"
}


var section: String = "funny section"

func someFuntion() {
  print(MyEnum.tapOnSection(self.section))
}
```

Console: "tap on funny section"

Do you some if could I do something like that or some suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Read this [doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html), section **Associated Values**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add methods to `enums`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
      case tapOnSection(section: String)

      var description: String {
         switch self {
             case let tapOnSection(section: section):
                 return "tap on \(section)"

         }
       }
} 



var funnySection: String = "funny section"

print(MyEnum.tapOnSection(funnySection).description)
```

Answer (score 3):

An `enum` can't have both associated values (i.e. cases with arguments) and raw values. That's a limitation of the language at the moment.

The simplest way I can think of to approximate what you want is to create a computed property that replaces the raw value in some way. e.g. for your specific case you can do this:

```
enum MyEnum
{
  case tapOnSection(section: String)
} 

// Might as well implement CustomStringConvertible so you  can do
// print(MyEnum.something) instead of print(MyEnum.something.description)
extension MyEnum: CustomStringConvertible 
{
    var description: String 
    {
        switch self 
        {
        case .tapOnSection(let section):
            return "tap on \(section)"
        // A switch case for each case in your enum
        }
    }
}

print(MyEnum.tapOnSection(section: "foo")) // prints "tap on foo"
```